# Understanding and parsing a cURL response

Tags: php

```
    var $conn = false;
    var $username = "";
    var $password = "";
    var $error = false;

   function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
    }

    function get($url)
    {
        $this->conn = new Curl('youtube');

        $html = $this->conn->get($url);

        if(strstr($html,'verify-age-thumb'))
        {
            $this->error = "Adult Video Detected";
            return false;
        }

        if(strstr($html,'das_captcha'))
        {
            $this->error = "Captcah Found please run on diffrent server";
            return false;
        }

    if(!preg_match('/encoded_fmt_stream_map.*/',$html,$match))
        {
            $this->error = "Error Locating Download URL's";
            return false;
        }

        $fmt_url =  substr(urldecode($match[0]), 1);
        $urls = explode(',',$fmt_url);
        $foundArray = array();

        foreach($urls as $url)
        {
        $url_end = strstr($url, "&quality");

       // $foundArray[] = $this->GetBetween($url, "&url=", "&type=");
        $foundArray[substr(strstr($url_end, "&itag="), 6)] = substr( (str_replace($url_end, "", $url)), 4 );

        }

        $formats = array(
            '5'=>array('flv','Low Quality'),
            '6'=>array('flv','Low Quality'),
            '13'=>array('3gp','Low Quality'),
            '17'=>array('3gp','Medium Quality'),
            '18'=>array('mp4','High Quality (480p)'),
            '22'=>array('mp4','High Quality (720p)'),
            '34'=>array('flv','High Quality (320p)'),
            '35'=>array('flv','High Quality (480p)'),
            '36'=>array('3gp','High Quality'),
            '37'=>array('mp4','High Quality (1080p)'),
//            '43'=>array('webm',''),
//            '44'=>array('webm',''),
//            '45'=>array('webm',''),
        );

        foreach ($formats as $format => $meta) {
            if (isset($foundArray[$format])) {
                $videos[] = array('ext' => $meta[0], 'type' => $meta[1], 'url' => urldecode($foundArray[$format]));
            } 
        }

        return ($videos);
    }
```

I'm parsing output from youtube(YT) inorder to play a video on my website. This code worked till recently when YT changed their format.

The part about this snippet I dont comprehend is from the "foreach($urls as $url)"

I get that he's parsing data returned from a curl request. I wrote the "GetBetween" fxn to pick bits and pieces of what I imagined was the relevant code, but it still returned a null array.

Can someone please explain what is being assigned to "$foundArray". Also what is being assigned to the "$videos[]" array. Do "$meta[0]" and "$meta[1]" refer to the first line of the array ie "'5'=>array('flv','Low Quality')" or the first two lines of the array?

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is neither complex not obfuscated...

Comment: Pick apart that line, look at each part. There's a substr inside of a substr, what's the inside one return? what's the outside one do to that? etc...

Comment: `echo()` and `print_r()` are your friends. if you display the strings/arrays/objects as the program walks through the function you'll get a much better idea of what is happening and why

Answer (score 0):

For each of the URLs in $urls, it takes the part of the URL before `&quality` and assigns it to `$foundArray[itag]`, where `itag` is the part of the URL after `&itag=` (I assume this is always the last parameter in the URL).

For the first line of the `$formats` array, `$meta[0]` is `flv` and `$meta[1]` is `Low Quality`. So the `foreach ($formats...)` loop goes through each format, looking to see if one of the URLs had an itag equal to the format number. If a match is found, it adds a row to `$videos` with the format information and a decoded version of the URL.

So the result will be that `$videos` contains an array where each row consists of an extension, video quality, and the URL to that version of the video.